# How do I get files back from the repo?

Tags: svn, repository, revert, rm

I `svn rm`-ed some files in my local working copy.

I have not `svn ci`-ed anything yet and I'd like to undo my scheduled removals and get the files back, `svn revert myfile1 myfile2` followed by a `svn up` didn't help.

**How can I get the files back from the repo?**

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the top directory and getting it back from the repo using `svn up` that seems to have worked well.
Thanks!